# Airflow GCSFileTransformOperator source object filename wildcard

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am working on a DAG that should read an xml file, do some transformations to it and land the result as a CSV. For this I am using `GCSFileTransformOperator`.

Example:

```
    xml_to_csv = GCSFileTransformOperator(
    task_id=f'xml_to_csv',
        source_bucket='source_bucket',
        source_object=(
            f'raw/dt=2022-01-19/File_20220119_4302.xml'
        ),
        destination_bucket='destination_bucket',
        destination_object=f'csv_format/dt=2022-01-19/File_20220119_4302.csv',
        transform_script=[
            '/path_to_script/transform_script.py'
        ],
)
```

My problem is that the filename has is ending with a 4 digit number that is different each day (File_20220119_**4302**). Next day the number will be different.
I can use template for execution date: `{{ ds }}`, `{{ ds_nodash }}`, but not sure what to with the number.
I have tried wildcards like `File_20220119_*.xml`, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dig on the operator [GCSFileTransformOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/a49224fa7ce45e9765c0d752edc30430e0d3ce14/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/gcs.py#L523) code and I dont think current wildcards will likely work as the current templates are fixed values based on the time of execution as described on [templates reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html) page and the source file will have a totally different filename.

My solution to this will be to have a python operator as an additional step which can find your input file first. Depending on your airflow version you might use [TASKFLOW API or XCOM](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-passing-data-between-tasks) to pass the filename data.

```
def look_file(*args, **kwargs):
    # look for file
    return {'file_found': filefounpath}

file_found = PythonOperator(
    task_id='file_searcher',
    python_callable=look_file,
    dag=dag,
)

xml_to_csv = GCSFileTransformOperator(
    task_id=f'xml_to_csv',
        source_bucket='source_bucket',
        source_object=(
            raw/dt=file_found
        ),
        destination_bucket='destination_bucket',
        destination_object=f'csv_format/dt=2022-01-19/File_20220119_4302.csv',
        transform_script=[
            '/path_to_script/transform_script.py'
        ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used something similar to your suggestion, just that I did not define a PythonOperator, just created a function that I'm using then in GCSFileTransformOperator source_object = function(param1, param2, param3). And inside function I'm using GCSHook to get the file.